# Django Settings not found error, but only sometimes

Tags: python, django

I have a standard Django project setup going on:

```
projectname/
  manage.py
  projectname/
    appnameone/
    appnametwo/
    ...
    settings.py
    wsgi.py
```

(I don't actually call them these names, but it's an accurate representation of the similarity of the folder names)

In wsgi.py we have:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/projectname')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projectname.settings")
```

Pretty standard stuff, all generated from `startproject` and `startapp` commands. And sometimes this actually works fine (usually after I've just done an Apache restart). But sometimes it doesn't work, and I get a 500 error. When I do, I check the apache logs and I invariably see this line every single time:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?)
```

The stack traceback attributes this to:

```
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/www/projectname/projectname/wsgi.py'
```

None of this makes any sense to me, as nowhere am I referencing a `myproject.settings`, but Python sometimes (and only sometimes) seems to try to load it.

Anyone have any tips for finding out where this erroneous `myproject` is coming from and casting it into the fires of hell? And why would doing an Apache reload temporarily cure this issue, only for it to resurface?

Comment: Have you ever used "myproject.settings" in your project? Are there some old .pyc files laying around?

Comment: Nope :( Just deleted all the pyc files to be sure, and it still went to a 500 a couple of refreshes later

Comment: Is it still the same error in the logs? Please share the complete wsgi file